# Image in Chrome not showing

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have this function in Js:

```
function MensajeCargandoJQUERY() {

        var imagenCargando = "cargandotransparente.gif"

    var MensajeCargandoDIALOG = $('<div class="Cargando" title="CARGANDO" style="text-align:center" ><img src="../Imagenes/'+imagenCargando+'" /></div>').appendTo("body").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: "200px",
        height: "auto",
        open: function (event, ui) {
            //hide close button.
            $(this).parent().children().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        MensajeCargandoDIALOG.dialog("option", "Cargando...", "Cargando...").dialog("open");
    });
```

}

This function is fired every time a user clicks on a menu item, the thing is that, when i use it on IE it shows the image(gif) but in Chrome, it doesn't.

Can anyone help me with this?, am i doing something wrong?

SCREEN SHOTS:

**IE**

[image]

**CHROME**

[image]

Comment: Press F-12, open the NETWORK panel, reload, look for 404 errors.

Comment: I am use to see the opposite has an issue.

Comment: i don't get any 404 error, this code works on IE but not in firefox and chrome

Comment: i've got the same problem and can't find a solution. I tried to put a js settimeout, add the image as css background of dialog, save the dialog into a var and then MyVar.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));, but none of these works still got an icon on chrome and the alt text in firefox ...

Answer (score 0):

Change your relative links to absolute within javascript

`<img src="../Imagenes/'+imagenCargando+'" /></div>`